# combining grepl and gsub to replace unwanted cells with NA

Tags: r

I am only interested in cells that contain a key word or a key number (let's say 2015 for instance). So, how to replace all other cells (that do not contain the key word "2015") in my `data.frame` with NA, using both `grepl` and `gsub`.

Comment: Where are the cells?  What I mean by that is that it would be best to post some of your data, show us what you've tried that didn't work, and then show the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `grepl` and logical indexing:

```
> dat <- data.frame(a=c("2016", "2015"))
> dat
  a
1 2016
2 2015
> i <- grepl("2015", dat$a)
> dat$a[!i] <- NA
> dat
 a
1 <NA>
2 2015
```

You can add `gsub` as well if you really need..

Comment: Ott Toomet, thanks for the prompt response. It did work when I specify one vector of my data.frame. How about to apply this to other variables (columns) of my data.frame. Should I list them all? Actually, I have 20 columns and 300 rows  in my data.frame. Please, advise. Thanks

Comment: So you have 20 columns where you want to change unwanted columns to NA?  You just repeat the example above for each column.  You may also repeat it in a loop like `for(j in 1:ncol(dat)) dat[[j]][!grepl("2015", dat[[j]])] <- NA` (untested).

Comment: A side note: do you actually want to remove these rows, or just to transform to NA?

Comment: No, I don't want to delete them. I will test the loop and see if it works. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Ott, the loop works perfectly...Sorry for those who gave me negative feedback for my silly question, but I am new to the R software (have been using this less than 2 weeks).

Comment: @ddkunda - People don't mind if you're new to R.  We will help you, but this site has its own standards.   You can read about them at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Ott, I am reaching out for help again. All my other columns contain dates and years except for the first column which contains subject ID numbers. I used the grepl to each column and it worked perfectly. I think using the loop is much faster, but when I used the loop alternative, all values in my subject column turn to "NA" as well (because i don't have any year in there). How can apply the loop to all other columns except for the first one?